# Edit every row in data.frame

Tags: r

I'm struggling with editing a dataframe. So my dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame( Att1 = c("Text Text", "Text2 Text2", "Text3 Text3"), Value = c(1,2,3))
```

[image]

But after every word in every row something(e.g. "∖n") should be added. For example like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do something like that?
Very help would be great!
regards

Comment: Try `df$Att1 <- gsub("\\s+", "\n", df$Att1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `sapply` one can see very clear what arguments are passed to `gsub`; `|` can be used to make alternations in regex

```
df <- data.frame( Att1 = c("Text Text", "Text2/Text2", "Text3-Text3"), Value = c(1,2,3))

df$Att1 <- sapply(df$Att1, gsub, pattern = "\\s+|\\-|\\/", replacement = "\n")

df$Att1
[1] "Text\nText"   "Text2\nText2" "Text3\nText3"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in a couple of ways.  If the space is single, then `chartr` can replace the space with `\n`

```
df$Att1 <- chartr(" ", "\n", df$Att1)
```

Or with `gsub`, we replace one or more spaces (`\\s+`) with `\n`

```
df$Att1 <- gsub("\\s+", "\n", df$Att1)
```

If we have `-` or `\`, then replace `\\s+` with

```
df$Att <- gsub("[ \-]+", "\n", df$Att1)
```

Comment: or you can use stringr package, like:
     str_replace(df$Att1, " ", "\n") or using regex patterns
     str_replace(df$Att1, "\\s+", "\n")

Comment: the gsub method worked perfectly, thank you! But what does the gsub() look like, if after every "-" , "/" and " " a "\n"should be added? So e.g. at strings like "Text-Text", "Text/Text" and "Text Text"

Comment: @Leon  Just replace the `\\s+` with `[ -/]+` in the pattern